# bestpractises for big react projects

Tags: reactjs

I want to develop my first reactjs project. It will be a big project with lots of views and components.

what would be a good best practise to get structure in it? ReactJS ist just for frontend stuff and the communication over REST with a Play framework backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say start from router. Make sure your router works if url is hit directly, for that you need fallback backend routes that will render React as well as it would render on `/` route. Or else, use something like [Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) that does it for you automatically.

If you are going to use cookies, it's good to implement them in early stage too.

I do not know what kind of app you are building, but I would suggest using Redux for global states. Some global state usage examples:

- Data from API that is used by multiple components
- Data from components that is used by other multiple components
- Shared states (loading, disables, for example if one button is clicked and loading and you want to disable other fields that are from different components, its good to have reducer for global loaders)

Since you are going to have a lot of views and components, create 3 directories, `components`, `containers`, `views`.

Use components directory for dumb (stateless) components.  Use containers directory for components with state. Each component may be a file or a folder that includes CSS and image files as well, and then include these directly within your component JS file. And finally views directory for each page.

As for build and other stuff, if you are not comfortable with webpack configurations, you could use `create-react-app` or again `nextjs2` starters.

I do not know what is your app about and what it should do, so I am unable to provide more hints. Hope this helped a bit.

In the future, consider using Stackoverflow for specific problem questions, and for questions such as this use reddit, facebook react group or other forums that allow generic questions.

Comment: It will be an Word alternative :)

Comment: Do you probably have a Tutorial for Cookies and Router?

Comment: In that case consider using https://facebook.github.io/relay/

Comment: Thanks for your hints

Comment: The Word Part is Only a Part Chatting And so on will be included aß Well

Comment: @Felix as for cookies I have an API which generates cookies for all my projects, and for react client I use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie.  It is super simple library. And as for router, consider using `react-router` with `browserHistory` rather than `hashHistory`. You might need to use  browserHistory API fallback in your webpack configuration.

Comment: Thanks a Lot ist think i will buy a book. :)

Comment: I didn't read any React related books so I can't suggest one. However, when I just got started I watched videos from this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrsle5quS7A  (you might want to watch React without Redux series first from the very same channel)

Comment: Oh okay Ist found a free 100 Pages book I will read And Thanks for the Link. For what ia redux?

Comment: Once you start writing react you will notice that your components can't communicate directly. They must use props from parent to child. In order for two children to communicate, they must use state from parent, which is very messy. This is where Redux comes to play. Redux is basically store where all global states are stored and reduced (separated). By using Redux, child components do not need to use parent state anymore, instead they can communicate via Redux.

Comment: So it would be more comftable  to use redux?

Comment: Yes Redux is very good choice. However, Redux is not the only one. You can also use others like Relay or Mobix. Also note that Redux is not React-specific (which means you can use it outside React projects), but it is pretty much built for it and I am pretty sure all projects use it, or one of its alternatives. Consider reading topics about Flux, which is architecture pattern that later introduced Redux.